# process_usershare_file: stat of failed. Permission denied Samba

Tags: linux, samba, permission-denied, ubuntu-14.04

I created a shared folder using samba in ubuntu to enable windows machines can access it with the following command:

```
$ sudo net usershare add documents /home/developer/documents "Developer documents" everyone:F guest_ok=y
```

I give 777 permissions to the folder:

```
$ sudo chmod 0777 /home/developer/documents
```

And then I check what I've done

```
$ sudo net usershare info --long
```

When I want to see if the folder is visible from all windows machine, you can see. However, you cann't access that folder and get error of: "Permission Denied"

The message in: `/var/log/samba/log.ip-domain` is:

```
process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/backuparsac failed. Permission denied
```

Then, I try to add some rules to my `smb.conf`

```
[documents]
   comment = Documents for Developers
   path = /home/developer/documents
   browseable = yes
   writable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = yes
   directory mask = 0777
```

but the error of Permission denied keeps coming. Is there anything else I need to do? I need this folder can be accessed by all windows machines.

NOTE: I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Aren't you on Ubuntu 14.04 ?
I have similar problem on it and cannot make it work. Tried by installing libpam-smbpass, and cifs-utils, but nothing made the error go away

Comment: You have both `read only = yes` and `writable = yes` - that might also not work

Answer (score 14):

The cause is that Samba does not synchronize its users with the system.
This solved the issue in my case, on Kubuntu 14.10:

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-smbpass
sudo service samba restart
```

If you don't want to synchronize users with PAM, simply add a user to Samba's password database:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <user>
```

After that, the user will be able to open shared folders on the Samba machine.

Comment: Installing libpam-smbpass worked for me, but instead of restarting samba service or either smbd service, worked just after restarting the computer.

Comment: Rather than rebooting can use `sudo service nmbd stop` and `sudo service smbd stop`. I always stop `nmbd` as well just to make sure. Then repeat the above two commands replacing `stop` with `start`.

Comment: Worked for me too, but I had to reboot (Linux Mint 17.3). Just restarting samba, nmbd, or smbd didn't do it. When I rebooted, I got a popup when signing back in saying "User added: <myusername>" which I suspect was libpam-smbpass doing its job.

Comment: A year after the answer, the package was removed: https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-cvs/2015-October/111473.html

Answer (score 6):

Your configuration file seems to be fine.

I reckon there might be a permission issue in your parent folder.

I suggest you check /home and /home/developer both have 755 rather than 750 permission.

Then check sudo -u nobody ls /home/developer/documents.

If ls is successful, the samba is likely to work as you expected as well

Comment: I totally missed the **x** flag, I don't think its represented well in nautilus file permissions dialog.